# cpp <chrono>- member type defenition

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I am learning cpp. I thought that memeber type are functions/variable which belong to a type.
For exanple in the following

```
class person
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
};
```

name and age are member type (in this case member class) of the person class.

Recently I started to read about `<chrono>` library, and thaen I started to confused.
There is  for example `class system_clock` which has `time_point` member type. But on the other hand there is also class `time_point` which has Clock member type (e.g class system_clock).

How can a class contains sompe type as a member type and also be a member type of its own member type.

I hope that I succeeded to explain my confusion.

Comment: Implementing `<chrono>` (or even understanding its implementation) is a very ambitious project for a beginner. :-)

Comment: @ Howard Hinnant- I have to....it's a part of a code in work:-0

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing *non-static data members* with *nested member type aliases*.

Examples of *non-static data member* are `name` and `age` in:

```
class person
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
};
```

`name` and `age` store values inside a specific instance of `person`.  They have an address in an lvalue instance of `person` so you can find out what that address is:

```
person p;
string* np = &p.name;  // this is where p.name lives in memory
```

A *nested type alias* does not occupy storage.  For example:

```
class person
{
public:
    using name_type = string;
    string name;
    int age;
};
```

`person::name_type` is a type alias for `string`.  It doesn't occupy storage.  You could use it to create a `string`:

```
person::name_type x = string{};
```

`system_clock::time_point` is a type alias for:

```
time_point<system_clock, system_clock::duration>
```

`time_point::clock` is a type alias for `Clock` in:

```
time_point<Clock, ...>
```

So, `time_point<system_clock, system_clock::duration>::clock` is the same type as `system_clock`.

`system_clock` does not store a `time_pont`.  Indeed, it does not store anything at all (no non-static data members).

`time_point` does not have a clock as a non-static data member.  `time_point` only stores a `duration` which has the type of `time_point`'s second template parameter in:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration = typename Clock::duration>
class time_point;
```

These type aliases might be used like this:

```
system_clock::time_point tp = system_clock::now();
```

Though the use of `auto` here is much easier (and my preference):

```
auto tp = system_clock::now();
```

Use of `time_point::clock` might come in handy if you had a generic `time_point` and you needed to call `now()` for whatever clock that `time_point` is measured with:

```
template <class TimePoint>
void some_function(TimePoint tp)
{
    using Clock = typename TimePoint::clock;
    auto now = Clock::now();
    ...
```

This latter use-case is more rare, but the capability is there if you need it.

In general, when learning about `<chrono>`, most people do better by reading tutorial-like information about it, or looking at example code, or reading other's Stack Overflow questions about it.  When people try to learn about `<chrono>` by studying its implementation, they invariably have a strong negative reaction to its relatively complex implementation.

Its implementation is relatively complex because it is far more powerful than alternatives such as `timespec`.  However its common everyday use has very simple and safe syntax.  For common use cases you don't even need to know that everything is templated.  You can just use things like `system_clock::now()`, `nanoseconds` and `hours`.

I recommend reading some of the [[chrono]-tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono) questions.  I also recommend reading *parts* of the `<chrono>` proposal found here:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm

The committee itself needed a tutorial on this subject, and this paper contains a pretty good one.  Skip the parts containing proposed wording unless you're in need of a sleeping aid.  The paper is somewhat dated in that a few details have changed, but not many.  One example is that `monotonic_clock` has since been renamed to `steady_clock`.  Another detail is that `constexpr` has since been generously applied.  And user-defined literals have since been added to the 6 concrete duration types.

Finally, [Nicolai M. Josuttis' second edition of The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference](http://www.cppstdlib.com) has a nice section on `<chrono>`.